# Using a Nexus repo as an upstream npm proxy in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, nexus

I have a client who is using Nexus Repo (3.0) and they have a specific npm-group repo (public and private) set up there. They want to use it in Azure DevOps as a source for their pipelines without having to use Azure Artifacts and preferably without having to make a change to each and every pipeline as there are many.

They are using Azure DevOps Server 2019.1 update 3.

I'm struggling to find any more info on this and if anyone can give me a yes/no answer or some guidance I'd appreciate it.

Kind Regards,
DB

Comment: So I've gone a slightly different route.

Answer (score 0):

You can check extension `Sonatype Nexus Repository Release Artifact`, which may help you:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=soft-cor.nexus-custom-release-artifact-extension

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately that only works for Maven repo's and not for npm.

Comment: Unfortunately, I couldn't find information indicates using a Nexus repo as an upstream npm proxy. I'm afraid it is not be able to achieve.